# Queue in flask with websocket

Tags: websocket, queue, flask, scrapy, gevent

I am using Flask, Gevent and scrapy for a project. The basic idea is that you enter a url and it starts a crawler process with the input as the arguments. It currently seems to be working well with the output piped through websocket.

I am curious what is the best way to handle multiple crawlers being run at the same time, so if two people input a url at the same time. I thought the best way to do this would be a queue system, ideally I only want a controllable amount of crawlers being run at the same time.

Does any have suggestions on how to go about this with the libraries I am already using? Or maybe suggest a different approach?

Comment: have you considered using nodejs ? you can have asynchronous calls for each crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Try nodejs , webtcp(for websockets) and asynchronous calls for each crawler. also once you are done with crawling you can save it in a temporary storage such as memcached or redis with a expiration key.

so when there is a similar crawl request you can serve it from temporary storage

Comment: Yea this particular crawl purpose, I do not need to worry about the content changing too much. Therefore I saved any parsed results from a crawl to json files. I would prefer if there was any easier way to achieve this without having to change how my app was built.

Answer (score 0):

If the crawler is a gevent job you can use a pool.

http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html

The Pool which a subclass of Group provides a way to limit concurrency: its spawn method blocks if the number of greenlets in the pool has already reached the limit, until there is a free slot.

pseudo code:

```
crawler_pool = Pool(10)

def spawncrawler(url):
    def start():
         crawler_pool.spawn(crawl, url)  # blocks when max is reached.

    gevent.spawn(start)
    # give a response to the browser. this will always succeed because
    # i put the spawning of the crawler in a separate greenlet so if max 
    # 10 crawlers is reached the greenlet just holds on untill there is space
    # and client can get default response..
```